# How to manipulate/clean data located in a MySQL database using base R commands?

Tags: mysql, r, database, dplyr, dbplyr

I've connected to a MySQL database using the RMariaDB package, and, thanks to the dbplyr package, am able to adjust the data using dplyr commands directly from R studio. However, there are some basic things I want to do that require base R functions (there are no equivalents in dplyr to my knowledge). Is there a way to clean this data using base R commands? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some examples of exactly what you need to do? You can still use base R function with `dplyr`. It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this arises from how the `dbplyr` package works. `dbplyr` translates certain `dplyr` commands into SQL. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
data(mtcars)

# setup simulated database connection
df_postgre = tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = simulate_postgres())

# fetch first 5 records
first_five = df_postgre %>% head(5)

# view SQL transaltion
first_five %>% show_query()

# resulting SQL translation
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `df`
LIMIT 5
```

The major constrain for this approach is that `dbplyr` can only translate certain commands into SQL. So something like the following will fail:

```r
# setup simulated database connection
df_postgre = tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = simulate_postgres())

# fetch first 5 records
first_five = df_postgre[1:5,]
```

While `head(df, 5)` and `df[1:5,]` produce identical output for data.frames in local R memory, `dbplyr` can not translate developer intention, only specific `dplyr` commands. Hence these two commands are very different when working with database tables.

The other element to consider here is that databases are primarily read-only. In R we can do

```r
df = df %>%
  mutate(new_var = 2*old_var)
```

and this changes the data held in memory. However in databases, the original data is stored in the database and it is transformed based on your instructions when it is requested. There are ways to write completely new database tables from existing database tables - there are already several Q&A on this under the `dbplyr` tag.